# Is there something like `org-blank-after-new-entry` for org mode headings?

Tags: org-mode

There is `org-blank-before-new-entry` to insert a blank line before a new entry. But is there a similar variable for adding a blank line after a new entry? It would be useful when inserting an entry between entries.

This question was previously asked on the site, but it seems to have been deleted:

- [[O] Is there something like ~org-blank-after-new-entry~ for org mode hea](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2017-01/msg00625.html)

  - http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/28742/is-there-something-like-org-blank-after-new-entry-for-org-mode-headings

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem myself using this hack. It seems to work okay.

```lisp
(defvar night/org-blank-after-new-heading-p t
  "If non-nil, insert a blank line after inserting a new heading in Org mode.")

(defun night/insert-blank-after-org-heading (&rest dummy)
  "Insert a newline after a new org heading if `night/org-blank-after-new-heading-p` is true."
  (when night/org-blank-after-new-heading-p
    (save-excursion
      (end-of-line)
      (insert "\n"))))

(advice-add 'org-insert-heading :after #'night/insert-blank-after-org-heading)
```

Comment: That will interfere with Org mode's abitlity to parse the entry e.g. for `DEADLINE` or `SCHEDULED` keywords or a property drawer (e.g. `LOGBOOK`). These things are supposed to come after a headline with no empty lines in between.

Comment: See https://orgmode.org/worg/org-syntax.html#Planning and https://orgmode.org/worg/org-syntax.html#Property_Drawers

Comment: @NickD Umm. When I insert a new heading, I don't have a property drawer by default. I don't really use the scheduled etc. functionality though, so maybe I just haven't encountered that need ...

Comment: I should have said that it *might* interfere: if you insert these things using the appropriate functions, they (the functions) might take care of everything - I haven't tried it. But if not, that might bite you in the future, so just keep it in the back of your mind.